# Reprojection problem when using QgsRasterFileWriter

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis, export

I'm using this script to export and reproject a selected raster layer with symbology applied. The output render file assumes the correct CRS but the image is not in the correct location. Am I forgetting some parameter?

In this case the reprojection layer is from EPSG:32721 to EPSG:4326

```
raster_selected = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
path_folder = 'home/user/test/'

for raster in raster_selected:
    raster_layer_name = raster.name().lower()
    
    dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
    
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(path_folder+raster_layer_name+'_render.tif')

    provider = raster.dataProvider()
    renderer = raster.renderer()
    
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())
    pipe.set(renderer.clone())
       
    
    file_writer.writeRaster(
                            pipe,
                            raster.width(),
                            raster.height(),
                            raster.extent(),
                            dest_crs,
                           )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `QgsRasterProjector` class and also transform the extent rectangle from source crs to target crs.

Try the code below:

```py
import os

raster_selected = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
path_folder = 'home/user/test'

for raster in raster_selected:
    raster_layer_name = raster.name().lower()
    
    source_crs = raster.crs()
    dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
    
    x_form = QgsCoordinateTransform(source_crs, dest_crs, QgsProject.instance())
    
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(os.path.join(path_folder, f'{raster_layer_name}_render.tif'))

    provider = raster.dataProvider()
    renderer = raster.renderer()
    
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())
    pipe.set(renderer.clone())
    
    projector = QgsRasterProjector()
    projector.setCrs(source_crs, dest_crs, QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
    pipe.insert(2, projector)
    
    
    file_writer.writeRaster(
                            pipe,
                            raster.width(),
                            raster.height(),
                            x_form.transform(raster.extent()),
                            dest_crs,
                           )
                           
    del file_writer
```

Comment: It worked and I learned a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: @geofausto, that's great! You're welcome :-)