# QgsRasterFileWriter in QGIS gives blank output

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to export the new Mapzen terrain to a local tiff for offline use (licence is open so no copyright issues).

I can easily do this in the interface by using Export -> Save As..

This allows me to clip to an extent, change crs, and set resolution and the export works exactly as I expect.

However if I try to do the same using Python and QgsRasterFileWriter I get the right size and shape but all pixels are set to 0. Sample code:

```
def clip_raster(raster, column_count, row_count, output_extent, crs):
    
    provider = raster.dataProvider()
   
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())

    temporaryFile = QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(temporaryFile)

    file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, column_count, row_count, output_extent, crs)
    newLayer = QgsRasterLayer(temporaryFile, 'NewLayer')

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newLayer)
    return newLayer
    
        
mapzen = iface.activeLayer()
spta = QgsRectangle(380989.09509790618903935, 136736.0862001694040373, 428067.31900055659934878, 159777.49075841635931283)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700)

newRaster = clip_raster(mapzen, 2000, -1, spta, crs)
```

The python adds the new layer almost instantly whereas the export takes a few seconds as you might expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422740/reprojection-problem-when-using-qgsrasterfilewriter/422762#422762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are saving your raster in a different CRS, you need to use the `QgsRasterProjector` class.

Try this modified version of your script below.

```py
def clip_raster(raster, column_count, row_count, output_extent, crs):
    
    provider = raster.dataProvider()
   
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())

    temporaryFile = QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(temporaryFile)
    
    projector = QgsRasterProjector()
    projector.setCrs(raster.crs(), crs, QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
    pipe.insert(2, projector)
    
    file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, column_count, row_count, output_extent, crs)
    newLayer = QgsRasterLayer(temporaryFile, 'NewLayer')
    
    return newLayer
    
        
mapzen = iface.activeLayer()
spta = QgsRectangle(380989.09509790618903935, 136736.0862001694040373, 428067.31900055659934878, 159777.49075841635931283)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700)

newRaster = clip_raster(mapzen, 2000, -1, spta, crs)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newRaster)
```

Comment: You are quite right. I did not think this was the issue as the empty image was in the right place but it obviously was as your revised code works exactly as I hoped. Many thanks

Comment: @Stuart Marsden, you're very welcome. Glad it worked.